# How do I get a String input to accept a possible integer in Java?

Tags: java, string, input, console, integer

I'm a very beginner at Java, and I'm creating a program that accepts user input in Java, and I'm trying to create a string that accepts strings or integers as responses. However, when I type in the acceptable integer, it won't recognize the answer. Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("How much time you you want to spend on this? Less than 30 mins, less than an hour, or more? Type \"30\", \"h\", or \"m\".");
    String ls = console.next();

    while (!ls.equalsIgnoreCase("h") && !ls.equalsIgnoreCase("m") && ls.equalsIgnoreCase("30")) {
        System.out.println("Type shit properly.");
        ls = console.next();
    }

    if (ls.equalsIgnoreCase("30")) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to do something fun? Y/N.");
        String dare = console.next();
        while (!dare.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !dare.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("Seriously?");
            dare = console.next();
        }
    }
```

Every time I type 30 into the console, it gives me my error report "Type shit properly" instead of proceeding to the "if ls equals 30" section. It works fine for the m and h options, just not the number. I thought strings accepted numbers as well; was I wrong? How do I get this to accept both Strings AND integers as input?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
&&ls.equalsIgnoreCase("30")
```

to

```
&&!ls.equalsIgnoreCase("30")
```

**or** if you want to allow any number, you could use [`String.matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)

```
&&!ls.matches("\\d+")
```

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you very much. Human error. One of the dumbest things I've done all day. (Thanks for answering.) Cheers.

Comment: Interesting; I didn't know about the allowing any number code; that'll definitely be useful, later on.

Answer (score 0):

use  `!ls.matches("30")` instead of `ls.equalsIgnoreCase("30")`